# WebSphere Application Server support of MicroProfile

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, microprofile

With the introduction of WebSphere Liberty there is confusion with the classic WebSphere Application Server.

For example WebSphere Liberty has support for MicroProfile and there is a lot of info about it, but it is hard to find information about support of MicroProfile in WebSphere Application Server.

I would like to know or find which WebSphere Application Server  versions support which MicroProfile versions.

Today I have WAS 9.0.0.3 ,  and I would like to move to a fix pack that gives a some MicroProfile support, the higher the spec the better.

Answer (score 4):

Traditional WebSphere Application Server supports only very limited set of MicroProfile APIs (1.0), as it only supports Java EE 7, and most of the MP apis require Java EE 8. Check this page for more details [MicroProfile programming model support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_microprofile.html).
Moreover, traditional WAS runtime is not a best match for MicroProfile apps, as it is large and heavy weight.

I'd strongly recommend using WebSphere Liberty runtime for your MicroProfile apps, as it was designed for such apps, and if you have license for WebSphere Application Server, you can use same license and use WebSphere Liberty runtime.